# Why $ker(i_*:H_0(\mathbb{S}^0)\to H_0(\mathbb{S}^2))$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

**Why $ker(i_*:H_0(\mathbb{S}^0)\to H_0(\mathbb{S}^2))$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$?**

I know that $H_0(\mathbb{S}^0)\cong \mathbb{Z}^2$ and $H_0(\mathbb{S}^2)\cong \mathbb{Z}$, so the problem is reduced to finding the kernel of $\mathbb{Z}^2\to\mathbb{Z}$, what is this kernel? Thank you.

Comment: Try actually identifying what the map is (just knowing it is a map $\mathbb{Z}^2\to\mathbb{Z}$ does not determine it uniquely).  What are the isomorphisms $H_0(\mathbb{S}^0)\cong \mathbb{Z}^2$ and $H_0(\mathbb{S}^2)\cong \mathbb{Z}$ explicitly, and how is the map $i_*$ defined?

Comment: What is the topological map $i$ which is inducing this map? As it is continuous, it should send $S^2$ to one of the two points in $S^0$. Using this you can show that the 0-chain associated to the other point in $S^0$, generating that copy of $\mathbb{Z}$ in $H^0(S^0)$, is in the kernel of the induced map of cohomology.

Answer (score 1):

Since $S^0 \cong \ast \amalg \ast$, we have a cell decomposition for it with two $0$-cells and no higher cells. Let's pick a cell decomposition for $S^2$ which has one zero cell and one two-cell. Then the cell complexes are:

$$C_\ast(S^0) = \mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z} \leftarrow 0\leftarrow \cdots$$
$$C_\ast(S^2) = \mathbb{Z} \leftarrow 0 \leftarrow \mathbb{Z} \leftarrow \cdots $$
and we can compute their cohomology as
$$H^k(S^0) = \begin{cases} \mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z} & k=0 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
$$H^k(S^2) = \begin{cases} \mathbb{Z} & k=0,2 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Now let's think about continuous maps $i: S^2 \to S^0$. Since $S^2$ is connected, the entirety of $S^2$ must map to a single 0-cell in $S^0$. This induces a map on 0-chains
$$C_0(S^2) = \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z} =C_0(S^0),$$
which sends $1\mapsto (1,0)$ (without loss of generality). Applying $\text{Hom}(-,\mathbb{Z})$ to the chain complexes and then taking homology, we get an induced map on the 0-th cohomology groups
$$H^0(S^0) = \mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z} = H^0(S^2),$$
which is of the form $(a,b)\mapsto a$, and hence has kernel $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Why " is of the form $(a,b)↦a$"?

Comment: Since there are no 1-chains, we can say that the final map is $F: H^0(S^0) = \text{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}) \to \text{Hom}(\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z}) = H^0(S^2)$, which is given by precomposition with the map $1\mapsto (1,0)$. Then use the isomorphism $\text{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$ and you should be able to see the result. If it's still unclear I can answer it in chat.

Comment: Yes it has been clear to me, thank you very much, By the way, is there a chat? Can you talk by chat in the forum? Could you tell me how please?